# How to "do nothing" in else part of if condition in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

In SML I must use the `else` part , since those are the rules of the language .

How can I do nothing in the `else` condition then ?

```
fun calc(input : string ) : int =

    let
      val outStr = ref "someString"
      val outInt = ref 0
    in
      outInt := (validateHelper(input) handle _ => ~1);
      if (outInt <> ~1) 
         then
            (  outStr := replaceRomanDec(input);       (* replace roman number with decimal *)
               outInt := (calcMyRomanExpression(!outStr) handle _ => ~1);
            )
         else (* nada *)

      !outInt
    end;
```

Comment: have you tried not even adding else?

Comment: You will want to adapt your thinking to functional programming. There are different ways to approach the whole problem in a non-procedural way without `if`. Just perusing the Wikipedia entry on SML shows an example of exactly that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
else ()
```

The value `()` is the unique inhabitant of the `unit` type. It makes the whole if-then-else construct well-typed, since the `then` branch also has type `unit`.

Finally, in some ML variants `if e1 then e2` can be used as shortcut for `if e1 then e2 else ()`, but not in SML.

Comment: Thank you my friend . Helped a lot ! +1 & chosen .

Comment: "Finally, if e1 then e2 can be used as shortcut for if e1 then e2 else (), so you can write that, too." doesn't work for me

Comment: @newacct Right you are. It is listed as a difference between SML and OCaml here: http://www.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/sml-vs-ocaml.html#control